# How to make sharp look of views in Scroll view on zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, zooming

I am working on application where I have a bunch of views (`UILabel`, `UITextField`, `UIButton` and etc). I enabled zooming and every thing working fine, but only one thing which is not good when user zoom in and want to look any view its gets pixelated and looking quite blurry. One thing which may be the reason I am using quite low font size as you may in below code, and I am not able to use high font because I am bound to use many views because to add many view in iphone litter size.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + 3;
textField.frame = rect;
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[textField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:5.0]];
textField.tag = fieldsYValue;
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO; // this is default value
[scrollView addSubview:textField];
```

Looking for any help who worked on this kind of projects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help.

This lets the user zoom in by a factor of 3 -- but when they do so, they're really just zooming up to full resolution, at which 1 pixel in the UIScrollView's content buffer is 1 pixel on screen.  (And of course, within our content view, we draw everything three times bigger to compensate.)  No need to implement any of the delegate methods except the standard viewForZoomingInScrollView; no redrawing at different scales depending on the zoom.

```
scrollView.contentSize = myContentView.bounds.size;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.33; 
scrollView.zoomScale = 0.33;
```

Comment: Thanks Akash but what is scale?

Comment: your zooming scale..any floating value

Comment: In this line this is showing me warning, "instance method contentScaleFactor not found"

Comment: scrollView.contentScaleFactor = 12; use like this

Comment: Yes did like this but nothing change, looking same as it was.

Comment: whats your scale value??